# Reading/writing utf-8 encoded data using Fiona?

Tags: pyqgis, ogr, python-2.7, shapely, fiona

So I have a 'cpg' file with my 'in_file' shapefile data (definitely
set to 'utf-8'). I was using 'meta' to create the same schema/crs as
'in_file'...though it runs, my text fields are borked on anything that
isn't ascii (note the cjk - 'ZH_CN' - is coming back as codepoints).

ex:

```
    {'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPoint', 'coordinates':
    [(13531245.475704141, 2886003.2689278126)]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id':
    '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'EN_US', u'Taipei City'), (u'ZH_CN',
    u'\u53f0\u5317\u5e02'), (u'ID', 1668338.0), (u'DE_DE', u'Taipei
    City'), (u'ES_ES', u'Taipei City'), (u'FR_FR', u'Taipei City'),
    (u'JA_JP', u'Taipei City'), (u'KO_KR', u'Taipei City'), (u'PT_BR',
    u'Taipei City')])}
```

My first thought was to change:

```
with fiona.open(in_file, 'r') as input:
```

to:

```
with fiona.open(in_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as input:
```

...but that resulted in:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in
position 0-2: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Reading it without the encoding seems to be the start of my
problem...however I was surprised that the error message arose when I
did the above.

```
def process_file(self, in_file, out_file, compare_file, dist):
    # open input file and compare file
    # loop over each
    with fiona.open(in_file, 'r') as input:
        meta = input.meta
        # The outFile has the same crs, schema as inFile
        with fiona.open(out_file, 'w', **meta) as output:
            with fiona.open(compare_file, 'r') as compare:
            # Read shapely geometries from file
            # Loop through all shapely objects
            # type(item) = 'dict'
                for item in input:
                    geom = item['geometry']
                    my_shape = shape(geom)

                    # check if it is a multipoint or point
                    if geom['type'] == 'MultiPoint':
                        # break Multipoints into points
                        # i.e. <class 'shapely.geometry.multipoint.MultiPoint'>

                        for pt in my_shape:
                            single_point = self.move_point(pt, compare, dist)
                            mpoint = MultiPoint([(single_point.x, single_point.y)])
                            mpoint_for_merge = shape(mapping(mpoint))
                            # write to outfile - WHERE EVERYTHING NOW WORKS
                            output.write({'geometry':mapping(mpoint_for_merge), 'properties': item['properties']})

                    elif geom['type'] == 'Point':
                        # return of move_point is a shapely geom
                        # i.e. <class 'shapely.geometry.point.Point'>
                        my_shape = self.move_point(my_shape, compare, dist)
                        # write to outfile
                        output.write({'geometry':mapping(my_shape), 'properties': item['properties']})

                    else:
                        raise ValueError('unhandled geometry type: ' + repr(geom.type))
```

Comment: look at [Find and replace unicode character in a shapefile](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58817/find-and-replace-unicode-character-in-a-shapefile/58825#58825)

Answer (score 6):

Fiona read ok utf-8 files without add nothing.

Try  **encoding='utf-8'**  only when output with fiona.

So change...

```
with fiona.open(out_file, 'w', **meta) as output:
```

To

```
with fiona.open(out_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8', **meta) as output:
```

And all must go OK.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem occured to me when working with GeoPandas. The solution @Juanma Font has written works with GeoPandas as well:

```
geodataframe.to_file(filename, driver='GeoJSON', encoding='utf-8')
```