# Unicode problems while writing selected features to a new shapefile with Fiona

Tags: python, shapefile, fiona, encoding, unicode

I have a shapefile with a large number of geographic features (marine protected areas).  I'm trying to read through all of the areas in the shapefile, select those that fit a certain criterion, and write a new shapefile with only the selected areas (areas with reefs).

Many of the areas have names with non-latin characters (i.e. in Swedish or Croatian).  I believe I have properly encoded everything in utf-8.

```
import shapefile
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import Point, shape
import pandas as pd

#read in habitat code list
hab_data = pd.read_csv(habitat_data.csv)

#read in shapefile
with fiona.open("all_protected_areas.shp") as source:
    polygons = [pol for pol in source]
    with fiona.open('reef_habitats.shp', 'w', encoding='utf-8', **source.meta) as outfile:

        #loop over polygons
        for i, poly in enumerate(polygons):

            #match the site code with the habitat code from csv
            sitecode = poly['properties']['SITECODE']
            habitatcodes = hab_data.loc[hab_data.SITECODE==sitecode]['HABITATCODE']

            #choose only reefs (1170)
            if '1170' in habitatcodes.values:

                outfile.write(poly)
```

The code works fine until I run into a polygon with a record containing non-latin characters.  The first one is: `('SITENAME', b'Obala izme\x1au rta \x8ailo i Vodoto\x1a')`.  The shapefile fails to write on the final line with:

```
ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'bytes'>
```

I'm using Python 3.  From my own investigations I've seen that there are some tricky differences in the way that Python 3 and 2.7 [handle unicode](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html).  There also seems to be some weirdness in [writing unicode](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140205/reading-writing-utf-8-encoded-data-using-fiona) with fiona.

By using Python 2.7 and various combinations of `.encode()` and `.decode()`, I've managed to get errors like `UnicodeEncodeError` and `UnicodeDecodeError` but no solution.

I'm open to using a different package if there is an easier way to do this feature selection.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything.  I believe the problem is in writing to the new shapefile.  I can, for example, print all of the records of each selected polygon no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fiona has a built-in parameter to specify the encoding of your data. Since you’re not explicitly setting the encoding, its probably defaulting to utf-8 (unless you are on windows). If your data is from a decent source it should specify the encoding somewhere in metadata. My best guess would be Latin-1.

```
with fiona.open(“all_protected_areas.shp”, encoding=”iso-8859-1”) as source:
```